# Drop all partitions from a table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, partition, sql-drop

How can I drop all partitions from a table in MySQL. I know you can drop specific partitions with `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PARTITION p0, p1`, but is there a way to not list every single partition name?

Comment: Drop all partitions == truncate table? Drop the table and re-create it without partitioning.

Comment: By drop all partitions I mean remove the partitions while keeping the data intact. From my understanding `DROP PARTITION` removes partitions while keeping data intact, and `TRUNCATE PARTITION` removes the data within the partition

Comment: *From my understanding DROP PARTITION removes partitions while keeping data intact* Investigate: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18911cca6bef434e87569490fd60d20e).

Comment: After looking at the documentation again you are correct, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ALTER TABLE table_name REMOVE PARTITIONING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html) can achieve what you want.

test [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37c00a79debefb877abb7949eacf4b54)